# Align GUI elements on wxpython's BoxSizer - equal spacing

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I wonder how (instead of using GridBoxSizer) can I align elements on panel, such I have equal horizontal spacing between elements? For now on, I came up with this:

```
label1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Emails Database File:")
label2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Email Start Number")

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(label1, 0, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(20, 15)), 0, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
sizer.Add(self.txtcontrol1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
sizer.Add(self.chooseFileButton, 0, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(label2, 0, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(25, 15)), 0, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
sizer.Add(self.spin, 1, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(self.infoLabel, 0, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(self.infoText, 1, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(self.progressBar, 1, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT, 5)
mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
```

It looks good on Kubuntu with KDE, but spaces are not equal on Mint with XFCE and Windows (any version). So I'm wondering, how can I do to lay out my elements to look exactly the same on every OS?

Can I somehow (and how?) calculate the size of the horizontal spacing to be equal on every OS?

On Kubuntu it looks great: http://s13.postimg.org/b9340sxbb/kubuntu.png

On Windows, not so great at all ... : http://s23.postimg.org/4et87799n/win.png

Sure I can prepare version for different OSes, but I would like to make it to automatically fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the images you sent, I can say that `GridBagSizer` is the best suited sizer for your requirements.

But if you want to do this with a bunch of `BoxSizer`s only, use `AddStretchSpacer` method instead of adding a blank `StaticText` inside the sizer.

And `wx.ALL` overrides `wx.LEFT` so you can remove `wx.LEFT` wherever it is used with `wx.ALL`.